# Последовательный вызов метода в Unity3d по истечению определённого времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю UI для своего интерфейса в игре, но у меня не получается создать уведомления при помощи скрипта.

Логика, которую хочу реализовать: Вызывается ОДНО уведомление и оно по истечению 5 секунд обратно выходит из экрана и уничтожается. Но если подряд вызвалось НЕСКОЛЬКО уведомлений, то уведомления поочерёдно сменяются друг за другом, но уже по истечению 1 секунды.

В чём суть, у меня есть 2 скрипта (третий скрипт для анимации `LeanTween` - есть в Asset store):

- Первый (`NotiesGameObject`) висит на самом уведомлении (сохранённом префабе) и срабатывает ТОЛЬКО когда объект появляется на сцене активным true (для запуска его `void Start()`). При старте запускается короутин, который по истечению времени (`yield return new WaitForSeconds(5)`) запускает анимацию, по истечению которой запускается метод `DestroyMe()`- (`LeanTween.moveX(gameObject, StartPosition.x, 0.5f).setOnComplete(DestroyMe);`)

  Вот сам `DestroyMe()`:

```
private void DestroyMe()
    {
        //Notification.instance - это Singleton, а notifications - List<T>
        Notification.instance.notifications.Remove(gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

- Второй скрипт, Singleton отвечающий за вызов уведомлений, в функции `CallMessage` задаёт уже название, тип и описание уведомления и вызывает метод `AddObjectContainer(cloneNotification);`, где `cloneNotification` - это игровой объект.

```
private void AddObjectContainer(GameObject objectAdd)
        {
            if (notifications.Count != 0)
                StartCoroutine(waitForNotification(EndMatch));
            else
                EndMatch();
            
            void EndMatch()
            {
                notifications.Add(objectAdd);
                objectAdd.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
```

Далее сам короутин IEnumerator, который отвечает за постепенный вызов

```
IEnumerator waitForNotification(Action end)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

            //В foreach хотел впихнуть WaitForSeconds, но проблема...
            foreach (GameObject notie in notifications)   
                LeanTween.moveY(notie, 5000, 5f); //5000 - это просто выкидывает вверх уведомление

            end();
        }
```

**Но вот проблема...** При вызове 4 уведомлений, т.к. действуйет `WaitForSeconds` то foreach не может работать, т.к. изменять List нельзя при работу foreach нельзя. Что можете порекомендовать?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: По умолчанию уведомление (префаб, откуда он берётся) - неактивный. Потом при помощи метода `EndMatch` он становится активным

Comment: Вынесите ответственность сдвига в отдельную функцию (не внутри как `EndMatch` и вообще зачем так делать). Все должно заработать. П.C. вы и так в `for` ничего не меняете в коллекции и вообще-то можно! Просто этот `for` должен идти на обратно с конца и сдвиг коллекции в результате удалений не влияет.

Comment: Можете ли вы добавить ваш ответ ниже, чтобы я мог его засчитать?